# Magento 2.1.7 Product EAV Reindexer issue

Tags: magento-2.1.7, reindex, indexer

I am very new to magento and am finding it ok to use (after overcomming a lot of issues it has) however i am now at one spot cdwhere i cant seem to resolved an issue i have with the Product EAV Indexer

> /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento index:reindex
>   catalog_product_attribute
>
> ```
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx.source_id' in 'field list', query
> ```
>
> was: INSERT INTO `mage_catalog_product_index_eav` (`entity_id`,
>   `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `value`, `source_id`) SELECT
>   `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`entity_id`,
>   `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`attribute_id`,
>   `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`store_id`,
>   `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`value`,
>   `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`.`source_id` FROM
>   `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` =
>   VALUES(`attribute_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `value` =
>   VALUES(`value`), `source_id` = VALUES(`source_id`)

Which if am correct states that i need the column **source_id** in `catalog_product_index_eav_idx.source_id`, However, When i add this column in and set the value to 0 for each row (i created a test database to see and that filled all the values with 0) i then get this error when running the same command

> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136
>   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT
>   INTO `mage_catalog_product_index_eav_idx` SELECT DISTINCT
>   `pid`.`entity_id`, `pid`.`attribute_id`, `pid`.`store_id`,
>   IFNULL(pis.value, pid.value) AS `value` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
>   `s`.`store_id`, `s`.`website_id`, `dd`.`attribute_id`,
>   COALESCE(ds.value, dd.value) AS `value`, `cpe`.`entity_id` FROM
>   `mage_store` AS `s` LEFT JOIN `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS
>   `dd` ON dd.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS
>   `ds` ON ds.store_id = s.store_id AND ds.attribute_id = dd.attribute_id
>   AND ds.entity_id = dd.entity_id LEFT JOIN
>   `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `d2d` ON d2d.store_id = 0 AND
>   d2d.entity_id = dd.entity_id AND d2d.attribute_id = 94 LEFT JOIN
>   `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `d2s` ON d2s.store_id =
>   s.store_id AND d2s.attribute_id = d2d.attribute_id AND d2s.entity_id =
>   d2d.entity_id LEFT JOIN `mage_catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON
>   cpe.entity_id = dd.entity_id WHERE (s.store_id != 0) AND ((ds.value IS
>   NOT NULL OR dd.value IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(d2s.value, d2d.value)
>   = 1)) AS `pid` LEFT JOIN `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `pis` ON pis.entity_id = pid.entity_id AND pis.attribute_id = pid.attribute_id
>   AND pis.store_id = pid.store_id WHERE (pid.attribute_id IN('136',
>   '139', '149', '161', '167', '169', '170', '171', '231')) AND
>   (IFNULL(pis.value, pid.value) IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT(pis.value IS NULL
>   AND pis.value_id IS NOT NULL))

I have been trying to solve this issue for quite a while now but am not having any luck.

I think I need to replace the core code which is used for the re-indexer but i cannot seem to find this.

Any chance someone could point me in the right direction on where Magento stores these files or how to resolve the issue using a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully solved this issue, by replacing the magento_indexer folder with a new version which I took from a new download of my Magento version. I then cleared the cache and did the Magento upgrade command. (i made sure I took a backup of the files I was replacing and the database before doing any of this).

The canceled all indexer process that was running, and re-run the indexer command and got the response I wanted.